# In Spring Data JPA, how to create and persist inner Entity by calling a method on an instance of outer Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Data JPA and contains a hierarchy of entities where a parent `Pod` entity logically owns a linked list of children `Pea` entities.

The parent `Pod` entity is basically this:

```java
package com.github.oie.entities;

import lombok.Getter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Getter
public class Pod {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Pea latestPea;

    public Pea nextPea() {
        // TODO:
        //this.latestPea = new Pea(latestPea);
        //persist(latestPea)  // <<-- I don't know how to implement this
        //return latestPea;
    }
}
```

The goal is to allow creation and persistence of children `Pea` entities via calling the method `nextPea` on the `Pod` instance.

The `Pea` class in this scenario is like this:

```java
package com.github.oie.entities;


import lombok.Getter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Getter
public class Pea {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Pea previous;

    public Pea(Pea previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public Pea() {
    }
}
```

And the desired use case is something like this:

```java
package com.github.oie;

import com.github.oie.entities.Pea;
import com.github.oie.entities.Pod;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@SpringBootApplication
public class OuterInnerEntityApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OuterInnerEntityApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Pod pod = new Pod();
        entityManager.persist(pod);
        Pea pea = pod.nextPea();  // <<-- this should both create and persist a new `Pea`
    }
}
```

Passing an instance of `EntityManager` to `nextPea` does not seem reasonable, as caller should not be required to have that.

What might be the 'proper' way to implement such arrangement?

P.S.

1. Naturally, a lot of non-pertinent code is omitted from examples above.
2. Build files for above code are:

```
// build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.github'
version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
// settings.gradle

rootProject.name = 'outer-inner-entity'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try using cascading for the `persist` operation in your `Pod` entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class Pod {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pea_id")
    private Pea latestPea;

    public Pea nextPea() {
        this.latestPea = new Pea(latestPea);
        return latestPea;
    }
}
```

This will automatically persist the `Pea` entity after you have persisted the `Pod` entity in your `run` method. You only have to create and set `Pea` to `Pod` before your persist `Pod`:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Pod pod = new Pod();
        Pea pea = pod.nextPea();
        entityManager.persist(pod);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for reminding me about cascading. I will experiment with this tomorrow, but for now it seems that this solution still requires manipulation outside of `nextPea` method (persisting parent entity after modifying it), which I believe to be unreasonable.

Comment: @CBlew, if you don't want to use cascading, you could also just persist `Pea` the same way you persist `Pod` in your run method - `entityManager.persist(pea)`. Otherwise, I don't see any other way of solving it. In my opinion, `entityManager` is not meant to be used inside of entities. Entities are _managed_ objects, so they should not be able to do any explicit operations on other entities or themselves with the `entityManager`. You should rather have some separate `DataManager` class, where `entityManager` will _manage_ your entities.